# Visual Studio 2013+ DB Project - Partial Schema / Import Partial DB Project

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I believe I am probably doing this wrong, but I am trying to create a DB Project in Visual Studio 2013 which only deals with a small subset of objects (tables, views, etc) from within an existing SQL Server database.

From looking online, I have found links detailing how to do this in Visual Studio 2010 such as:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193248(v=vs.100).aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172128(v=vs.100).aspx

But it doesn't seem the same options are available in VS2013.

Simply put, how can I accomplish the task of importing just a small selection of DB objects from an existing SQL Server instance into visual studio so as to be able to compartmentalize my development?

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you should do the next steps to achieve your goal.

1. Add a new database project to your solution.
   [image]
2. Right click on the database project in the solution explorer and select Schema Copmare.
   [image]
3. Left part will be predefined with a path to your database project. You should select a target schema and create connection to your database.
   [image]
4. If you want to update a database project from an existing database you should switch source and target and press Compare.
   [image]
5. Now you can see all objects which you can check for adding to your database project.
   [image]
6. Finally you should click Update for updating your target schema.

I hope I answered your question.

Comment: That is **PERFECT**!!!! - Thank you SOOOOOOOOOOO MUCH!!!! - Exactly what I wanted!!!

Comment: It won't let me award the bounty yet, but as soon as I can, I will.. THANK YOU!!!